# MessageBox close another form

Tags: c#

Hello Guys I have msg box when i press on yes its close that form which calls msg box
how can i do when msg box dialogresult = ok close only himself

Comment: How does your code look like that calls the MessageBox and closes the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `DialogResault` property to `None` for the button which its event handler open the MessageBox.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Click yes to close, otherwise click no.", "Message Box Test", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
  Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're assigning the result to the `DialogResult` property of the parent form,  (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) and in particular from the remark section :

> " If the form is displayed as a dialog
>   box, setting this property with a
>   value from the DialogResult
>   enumeration sets the value of the
>   dialog box result for the form, hides
>   the modal dialog box, and returns
>   control to the calling form."

Use:

```
   if (MessageBox.Show(...) == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
   }
   else
   {
   }
```